# Differentiate of Object Creation

Tags: java, inheritance

Please clarify the following object creation differences.

There are two classes: `Bike` and `Honda`. `Bike` is a super class and `Honda` is a subclass.

I have instantiated both the classes as follows and I need to know what the differences are in creating an object for subclass and creating an object for child class and assigning it to super class.

```
package program;

class Bike{
    public void display1(){
        System.out.println("Class 1");
    }
}

public class Honda extends Bike{
    public void display2(){
        System.out.println("Class 2");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Bike b=new Honda();
        Honda h=new Honda();
    }
}
```

Thank You

Comment: You already have used the correct tag `inheritance`.. now its time to use a search engine....

Answer (score 0):

program to interfaces, not implementations is a best practice or pattern people followed while writing code.Interfaces  are just contracts or signatures and they don't know anything about implementations.Coding against interface means, the client code always holds an Interface object This way the client program is not worried about implementation and the interface signature determines what all operations can be done. This can be used to change the behavior of a program at run-time. It also helps you to write far better programs from the maintenance point of view.

If you use concrete class so you can not change the behavior. Also difficult to test.For above case you can create your own stub of class on which your class depend upon.